# How to change a href link with gulp

Tags: javascript, html, function, replace, gulp

I'm creating a task with gulp that need to change the parameters of a href.
For example:

On my html file I have a link:

```html
<a href="myfolder">Click here</a>
```

So, "myfolder" is variable and refers to the name of the folder where the index.html is.
When I push the file onto the server, the page do not display as is not targeting the index.html file, but just the name of the folder.

I used gulp-replace for the task in the following way:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-replace');
 
gulp.task('templates', function(){
  gulp.src(['index.html'])
    .pipe(replace('<a href="*/" >', '<a href="*/index.html >"'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build/'));
});
```

As the folder name  (myfolder) is variable because every time I'm working on the project I have to create a new folder and at the end the index.html file cannot contain just a specific name.

So, this method didn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Kind regards,

Fernando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a regex in your `replace` call and match the part inside `href`:

```
replace(/<a href="(.*)"/g, '<a href="$1/index.html"')
```

Comment: can you give me an example?

Comment: Hi alexloehr, see below the example.                                                               
        <li><a href="Project1/" class="done">Project1</a></li>
        <li><a href="Project2/" class="done">Project2</a></li>
        <li><a href="Project3/" class="done">Project3</a></li>
        <li><a href="Project4/" class="done">Project4</a></li>

Comment: sorry, did you delete your question?